# Getting a weird black texture everytime moving the Mouse over a button

Tags: interface

Just downloaded Blender (I hardly know anything about it), and the same black texture appears/flutters when highlighting or scrolling/moving the mouse over a Button or another UI element.

p.s: I'm from Germany, my english isn't the best.

Edit: Some Details about my Hardware/Software (not really good , just wanted to try a Software like Blender)
    -OS: Windows 8.1 64 bit; x64 based CPU
    -8 GB DDR3 RAM
    -CPU: AMD Quad-Core Processor A10-7300; 1.9 Ghz
    -Graphic chipset: AMD Radeon R7 m265; 2GB dedicated VRAM and AMD Radeon R6 graphics (Driver Version: 13.351.1002.1002)

2nd edit: In AMD Catalyst Control Center, I put everything on high/maximizing Performance; but I'm still having These Problems with Blender. I searched for Driver updates in device manager, too, found none. Are there any other ideas?

[image: Looks like this]

[image: It's at other positions, too]

Comment: That isn't a texture, it's a problem with drivers for your GPU, Blender's interface can't be re-drawn properly. Update / rollback graphic drivers, Blender relies on OpenGL to draw its interface so maybe your card either is AMD or has old drivers etc.

Comment: @Mr. Zak: What do you mean with: "either its amd or..."? Does that mean it doesn't work because of an amd graphic card? (I got an amd)

Comment: AMD graphic cards sometimes don't work reliably with Blender. It depends on which one do you have, what operation system do you use.. and many more details. To add details to your question [edit] it, to add comment add it below your question

Comment: @MrZak - I'm using AMD/Ati GPUs and drivers since the mid 2000s and never had problems like that (not counting problems with nvidia and Intel gpus). So everything hardware-related is pure speculation until the OP provides sufficient information about his hardware.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser - we can't help you until you provide sufficient information about your hardware setup and operating system. I am exclusively using AMD/Ati Cards since 2005 and never ever had redraw problems like that. Again - please provide more info about your setup.

Comment: @metaphor_set i already edited the question, which further information do you need?

Comment: @someWindowsUser - the m265 chipset indicates that you are using a Laptop. Many R7 Mobile GPU Laptops have Dual Graphics Chipsets that also use CPU-internal graphics features in some energy saving modes. Be sure to connect your Laptop to the power supply or create a high-energy profile for Blender in the Radeon Settings.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser - please See my comment under your original question.

Comment: @metaphor_set thanks a lot! I'll try doing it. And yes, it's a laptop.

Comment: Do you mean the AMD Catalyst control center? If yes, i put everything on maximize performance, but i still have these problems.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser - Use this guide to force Blender on GPU instead of APU. https://community.amd.com/docs/DOC-1581 If you are still using CCC try upgrading to a more recent driver version. Sufficient Information also includes the driver version.

Comment: @metaphor_set downloaded a recent driver version on AMD website, and I followed the tutorial (was the same what I meant before) but I'm still getting the issues. I added the driver version to my question, too. Have you got any other ideas?

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser - so you added Blender to the applications list, switched the settings for it to "high performance" and checked via performance monitor that it uses the correct GPU? Those are the things I did on an old HP Laptop and it works (at least as well as one can expect from a five year old Laptop, no artifacts, thoug... ). Other than that - 13.x is a fairly old driver. Try this (http://support.amd.com/de-de/download/mobile?os=Windows%208.1%20-%2064) instead.

Comment: In fact, it was already using the correct  gpu with high performance. I just noticed that the driver is from 2014, too, so I'll try that again. Thanks for helping me out on this.

Comment: Finally got my driver updated properly, seems like it's working out, thanks.